# Merge HTML website with a React app sharing authentication

Tags: html, reactjs, authentication, merge, firebase-authentication

I have a React application and I need to embed it into an HTML web page in which users must log in to access.  I have tried a few things but have no functional results.  Both sites are connected to the same database in Firebase, I need to combine the sites and make the token obtained in the HTML site valid for the React App

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as preparing an empty tag withn this html page and then just rendering your React part into it..